# Spread rsync over several separate calls

Tags: rsync

I need to transfer a very large file with rsync (~1TB), but only transfer during a certain times (at night). The transfer takes longer than a single night, so I'd like to spread it across multiple calls.

What would be the easiest way to do that?

I'm currently thinking of using the --append switch, and simply killing the rsync process at the end of the allowed window. Will rsync properly handle the kill signal? Or is there a better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--partial` is what you are looking for. I'd also recommend `--delete`, so you clear out any extraneous files in the destination, and `--progress`, so you can see what is happening.

I have regularly used the above and killed an rsync transfer part way through. It works correctly.
 | 
`--dry-run` is useful for testing your arguments. Additionally, you can use `--bwlimit` which may mean you can run it during the day, too.

Comment: I just read http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48298/can-rsync-resume-after-being-interrupted saying that even called with --partial, rsync will delete the temporary file if interrupted by the user (not by a network failure). Is this true? If so, it doesn't sound like a good solution. EDIT: After tests, the file is indeed kept.

Comment: You can always kill instead of interrupting. Maybe not as clean, but it should not cause problems.

Comment: --partial does NOT behave that way for me. Very specifically, I routinely CTRL-C my transfers.

Comment: Also just noticed that --append actually implies --partial, so this might explain the similar behaviour I'm seeing.